# Why aren't default function parameters set each time the function is called in Python?

Tags: python, parameters

Why does this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep,time

def test_func(tmp=datetime.now()):
    print(tmp)

test_func()
sleep(10)
test_func()
```

..result in this:

```
2015-02-16 17:06:28.283351
2015-02-16 17:06:28.283351
```

..when I would expect this:

```
2015-02-16 17:06:28.283351
2015-02-16 17:06:38.283351
```

**Edit - changed the sleep to 10 seconds and the result is the same.

Comment: To the down-voter / vote-to-closer: what is unclear about that?

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of that question. I couldn't find anything similar when I searched. Robert Lifrido's answer says it all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1145781/15369

Comment: when the entire module is loaded first, datetime.now() is resolved to whatever datetime.now() was at that time. so more or less it is saying `def test_func(tmp='2015-02-16blablabla')`